# R regex to find and replace code in rstudio

Tags: regex, r, rstudio

I would like to make several changes to a code script. I  need to change the way how certain dataframes were subsetted. Specifically I need a way of using regex for editing my code with R studio.

I need to transform several dataframes that follow this format,

```
 variablex_indicatory$n[i]
```

To this,

```
 variablex_indicatory$n[variablex_indicatory$n==i]
```

Since I have many combinations of variables and indicators (e.g. `variable1_indicator2`, `variable3_indicator1`, etc.). what I need is to be able to replace what is after `$n[`  from `i]` to `variablex_indicatory$n ==`

So I need to specify in regex, find `$n[` and replace with `$n[whatever is before $n goes here ==`

I would left the `i` untouched as it does not need to be change.

How to do this surpases my current knowledge of regular expressions (obviously) I hope someones can help, thanks in advance again and please let me know if I was not clear enough.

Comment: RStudio's built in find function lets you use regex. why not go that route?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming each line looks roughly like this: `variablex_indicatory$n[i]`, then you can put this regex in the find box: `(^.+)(\$n\[)(i\])` and this regex in the replace box:  `\1\2\1==\3` and click "replace all."

If you have more complex code, then you need to do a better job of defining the first group (My example selects from the beginning of the line up to the dollar sign (`$`)).  Here's one variation for the first group: `(variab.+)`.  What you actually use will depend on the unspecified specifics of your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string<-"variablex_indicatory$n[i]"
first<-sub('\\[.*]','',string)
second<-sub('.*\\[(.*)\\]','\\1',string)
paste(first,'[',first,'==',second,']',sep='')
```